# SSH via private key works, but not SFTP via FileZilla on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

I'm facing the problem, that SSH works using a public/private key, but not SFTP via FileZilla. The key is added to FileZilla. When I do try to connect, it says:

FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I set PasswordAuth to no in the ssh config. I also restarted both my PC and the server. I hope you can help :)

Also, I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an old machine with the same settings, SFTP works there.

Answer (score 3):

This fix I use for this is to add the below line in to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```