# Problem with SFTP: "Credentials were not accepted by the server"

Tags: ssh, ftp, aws

I'm using an instance of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS via AWS, having enabled ports 22 and 443 in Ubuntu via ufw, and I'm using a Security Group with those same ports enabled.

Although I'm able to connect via SSH using a `.cer` key file, when I attempt to connect via SFTP with the same credentials I get the message:

> Credentials were not accepted by the server

I'm using Transmit for Mac, and having built environments using Ubuntu before with the same type of configuration (`.cer` key file and so on), this problem is new to me.

Some recommend installing vsftpd, but I'd prefer not installing and configuring anything until I know for certain I need to, and this isn't something fixable with what I have.

I found [an answer here in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437548/703716) and I was wondering if this is a possible fix?

I ran: `systemctl status sshd` and found the following:

> error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for ubuntu from
> [IP redacted] port 50773 ssh2 [preauth]

Comment: Please try with the `-v` option to see what happens.

Comment: Transmit doesn't provide CLI options.

Comment: I never used a Mac, but doesn't your Mac provide commands like `ssh` and `sftp`? Or you can try https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?platform=osx

Comment: I ran: `sftp -v ~/.ssh/[key-file].cer ubuntu@[IP address]` and got: `OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to /users/macbookpro/.ssh/[key-file].cer port 22.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /users/macbookpro/.ssh/[key-file].cer: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Connection closed`

Comment: you're missing `-i` in front of the path to your key-file

Comment: I changed it to: `sftp -iv` and got: `Warning: Identity file v not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /users/macbookpro/.ssh/aws-under-cloud-v5-ec2.cer: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Connection closed`

Comment: Not in front of `-v`, in front of the path to your key-file

Comment: Any chance you could write out the instruction? Otherwise it's total guesswork at this end.

Comment: `-i` in front of the path to the cert is quite a simple instruction imho, or check the man-page which says `[-i identity_file]`. ---> `sftp -v -i ~/.ssh/[key-file].cer ubuntu@[IP address]`

Comment: Looks like I got a connection: `sftp>` but there's too much here to paste into a comment — what do you need to see?

Comment: If the `sftp`  sub-command `ls` displays a list of the remote files, you are good. However, for the problem of **Transmit for Mac** you have to ask to a Mac forum I guess.

Comment: As explained, I'm using Transmit to connect to Ubuntu, Amazon Linux 2 and others with no problems, so the problem here is with this instance of Ubuntu, not Transmit.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, `MaxAuthTries` was part of the problem.

First, I ran the command: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and removed the # to enable the line.

I followed the instructions in [an answer to an existing question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437548/703716), and added the line: `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`

Then I ran the command: `sudo systemctl restart sshd` and I was able to connect with Transmit without problem.